# Condition variance of $\hat{\beta}$ different under heteroskedasticity

Tags: mathematical-statistics, least-squares, econometrics

I am following Bruce Hansen's Econometric textbook. Under the assumptions that $\{x_i,y_i\}$ are i.i.d., $E(e_i|x_i) = 0$, and errors are heteroskedastic, we derive the variance of the OLS estimator

$var(\hat{\beta}|\textbf{X})= (\textbf{X}'\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}'D\textbf{X}(\textbf{X}\textbf{X})^{-1}$ where $D = E(\textbf{e}\textbf{e}'|\textbf{X}) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & 0        & \cdots & 0\\
0        & \sigma_2^2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots\\
0        & 0        & \cdots & \sigma_n^2\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$
and $\sigma_i = E(e_i^2|\textbf{X})$.

Since the sample is i.i.d. we can assume that errors are drawn from the same distribution. Thus, can we say $\sigma_1^2 = \cdots = \sigma_n^2 = \sigma^2$ where $\sigma^2$ is some function of $\textbf{X}$? And so, $D=\sigma^2I_n$. The conditional variance term then becomes $\sigma^2(\textbf{X}'\textbf{X})^{-1}$. This is simplification of the original equation. Note the difference between this and the homoscedastic case, where under homoscedasticity $\sigma^2$ is a constant and not a function of $\textbf{X}$.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Note that the i.i.d. property applies marginally to the $x_i$ and $y_i$, which is different from stating that $y_i | X$ are i.i.d. across all $X = x_i$

Comment: I.i.d does not imply that $y$ given some $x$, across the support of $x$, are i.i.d—I completely agree. Yet, I believe $e_i$ are still i.i.d., which allows me to preform the above calculations. Do you disagree?